# C# .net Application cannot access sql server in terminal services

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, citrix

I have written a c# application that access an ms sql server.  I have had no issues with development of the application.  I am now at the deployment stage and a strange issue has cropped up.  The application is going to be served to the end user through terminal services.  For some reason the application cannot access the database if it is being executed by a standard user, it only can access it if the user is a member of the domain admin security group.  I can access the database if I server the user the SQL Management Studio or if I connect to the database with a ODBC dsn.  It seems to be something related to .net applications, specifically.  I am serving the applications through citrix, but also have a 2x environment and i have the same issue in both.  It must be something with terminal services and .net.

Any suggestions or people's experience with similars issues would be welcome.

Edit:

Here is the exception I get when the user is not a member of the domain admin group

System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.Connect(ServerInfo serverInfo, SqlInternalConnectionTds connHandler, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, Int64 timerExpire, Boolean encrypt, Boolean trustServerCert, Boolean integratedSecurity, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.AttemptOneLogin(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean ignoreSniOpenTimeout, TimeoutTimer timeout, Boolean withFailover)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.LoginNoFailover(ServerInfo serverInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, TimeoutTimer timeout)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds.OpenLoginEnlist(TimeoutTimer timeout, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlInternalConnectionTds..ctor(DbConnectionPoolIdentity identity, SqlConnectionString connectionOptions, SqlCredential credential, Object providerInfo, String newPassword, SecureString newSecurePassword, Boolean redirectedUserInstance, SqlConnectionString userConnectionOptions, SessionData reconnectSessionData)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnectionFactory.CreateConnection(DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, Object poolGroupProviderInfo, DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.CreatePooledConnection(DbConnectionPool pool, DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions options, DbConnectionPoolKey poolKey, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.CreateObject(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.UserCreateRequest(DbConnection owningObject, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, UInt32 waitForMultipleObjectsTimeout, Boolean allowCreate, Boolean onlyOneCheckConnection, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionPool.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningObject, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionFactory.TryGetConnection(DbConnection owningConnection, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions, DbConnectionInternal oldConnection, DbConnectionInternal& connection)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionInternal.TryOpenConnectionInternal(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.ProviderBase.DbConnectionClosed.TryOpenConnection(DbConnection outerConnection, DbConnectionFactory connectionFactory, TaskCompletionSource`1 retry, DbConnectionOptions userOptions)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpenInner(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.TryOpen(TaskCompletionSource`1 retry)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.Open()
   at CamLabs.UtilityClasses.DBConn.isConnected()
ClientConnectionId:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000

When they are a member of the group it runs with no errors.

Comment: I can't make sense of "I can access the database if I server the user the SQL Management Studio" - could you try re-phrasing/re-writing that bit please?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I updated with the exception

Comment: Can you please re-visit that sentence I highlighted? It seems to contain fragments of about three different sentences and there's not enough information for me to disentangle those sentences (or if it's meant to be a single sentence, I can't transform it into a sentence I can make sense of just by changing one or two words) - I literally have no idea what you're trying to convey to us.

Answer (score 0):

rHope the problem is in your connection string. It could be that you are using Integrated security option in your connection string. if yes- please change your connection string to the one that use SQL Server authorization. Do not forget add the user and the user mapping to the corresponded database. https://www.connectionstrings.com/

Comment: I am using sql server authorization, and the connection strings works as it should with members of the domain admins group, non members get the above exception.

Comment: From what you say I still doubt to the connection string...
It could happen that acting on behalf of admin user you are able to pull out a correct connection string (form a your settings store), but as a regular user you are using a wrong connection string. Try to debug or log Connection string value from your SqlConnection object when you are acting as a regular user. does it fit the value you see under administrator? are you using (local) or (.) in specifying instance in your connection string? if yes - replace it to the computer name.

Comment: also pay attantion at the following " Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections."
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/walzenbach/archive/2010/04/14/how-to-enable-remote-connections-in-sql-server-2008.aspx